# Path-connectedness in $n \times n$ invertible matrices.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices $A$ with real entries and $\det(A) \not= 0$.
>   Sending $A = (a_{ij})$ to the vector $(b_k)$ with $b_k = a_{ij}$ for $k = (i - 1)n + j$ represents
>   $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ as a subset of the Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$ of dimension $n^2$. We give $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ the subspace topology.
>
> (i) Show that the determinant function $f: GL_n(\Bbb{R}) \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

We have $$|A| = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(\text{sgn} \space \sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}...a_{n\sigma(n)}.$$The determinant function is continuous because it is a polynomial, and all polynomials are continuous.

> (ii) Show that $I$ and $-I$ lie in different path components of $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ if $n$ is odd.
>   (Here $I$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.) Show that $I$ and $-I$ lie in the same path
>   component if $n$ is even. (Hint: try the case $n = 2$ first.)

Let $n$ be odd. Since the determinant function (call it $f$) is continuous, two points in $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ are path-connectd by $\gamma$ if and only if the two images of these points are connected in $f(\Bbb{R})$ ($f \circ \gamma$ connectes the two points in the image). So it suffices to show that the image of $I$ and $-I$ under $f$ is not path connected. Since these are triangular matrices, the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries. We have $f(I) = 1$ and $f(-I)=-1$. Since $0 \not\in \Bbb{R}$, $1$ and $-1$ are not connected in the image, implying that $I$ and $-I$ are not connected in $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$.

Now let $n$ be even. Let $G$ denote $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$ as described in the question. I need to show that there is a continuous function $\alpha: [0,1] \rightarrow G$ with $\alpha(0)=(1,0,1,0)$ and $\alpha(1)=(-1,0,-1,0)$. However, from the universal mapping property of the product topology, we know that $\alpha$ is continuous if and only if each $\alpha_i$ is continuous for $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4)$. We can define $a_2$ and $a_4$ as the constant function that maps everything to zero. Now I need to find continuous functions $a_1$ and $a_3$ with $a_j(0)=1$ and $a_j(1)=-1$ for $j=1,3$. But I cannot see how this is possible, because $0$ is not in the 1st or 3rd component of $G$. So how am I supposed to connect $1$ and $-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the off-diagonal elements to a constant 0. This essentially puts you back into the odd case, which simply does not work. Instead you will need to use the off-diagonal elements to your advantage and as a room to maneuver.

Maybe you can think of it geometrically. In any dimensions, $I$ simply corresponds to the identity and $-I$ is a reflection of all coordinates. However in even dimensions, reflecting all coordinates is the same as a Rotation by 180°. So you should try rotations.

Take the matrix
$$M(t) = \pmatrix{\cos(t)& -\sin(t) \\ \sin(t) & \cos(t)}$$
corresponding to a rotation by t. This always has $det M(t) =  1$ and we have $M(0) = I$ and $M(\pi) = -I$. Higher even dimensions should be easy from here.